# AngularJs - two way binding in an ng-repeat with a view model

Tags: angularjs

I have a series of checkboxes in my ng-repeat as such:

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in blogCategory.items track by $index">
     ....
   <td>
      <label class="toggle">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle" checked="checked"
         ng-model="blogCategory.items[$index].publish" ng-true-value="'YES'" ng-false-value="'NO'">
         <i data-swchon-text="YES" data-swchoff-text="NO"></i></label>
  </td>
</tr>
```

I have 2 category items in my sample, the first one is a false for publish, the second is a true. They are both returning as (false)/NO on the checkbox element.

The $scope vm is BlogCategory, the property/field is publish.

How do I correctly bind the input element above?

Thanks

Comment: can u make a fiddle?

Comment: What does your `data-schwon-text` directive do?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like angular has changed parameter types for `ngTrueValue` and `ngFalseValue` from a string in 1.2.x to an expression in 1.3.x.

Try removing the single quotes around the values to make it look like

`ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO"`

You were probably looking at the documentation on `latest` as that's where it defaults to but your version may be 1.2.

https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.27/docs/api/ng/input/input%5Bcheckbox%5D

Answer (score 0):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/nx22cwwg/1/

So your problem is at the ng-model. You want item.publish there. So in my code ( which is almost the same as yours, I didn't look at exact property names and stuff ) I have:

```
<ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox-toggle" checked="checked"
       ng-model="item.isPublished" ng-true-value="YES" ng-false-value="NO" />
        {{ item.name}}
       </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I don't think that is the issue, `items[$index].isPublished` works as well.

Comment: Good point - although it is devious in my opinion. But you are right indeed. Then I'd check the parentheses in the ng-true-value - or check any other differences with my jsfiddle.